# jQuery : adding value overtime

Tags: jquery

if i press 1 button, it will ask whenever i am silver or gold.

if i click silver, my bonus will add by +150 000
right now i'm working with expetation, my bonus will :
increment by 150k, 300k, 450k and so on

but now,
the output is 0150000150000150000

here is my code

```js
var currentCircleId = '';
var balance='0'
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".circle").click(function(){
        $(".selection").toggle();
        currentCircleId = $(this).attr('id');
    });
    $('.selection').click(function(){
        $(".selection").toggle();
        var newClass = $(this).data('new-class');
        $('#' + currentCircleId).removeClass('gold silver').addClass(newClass);
    });

    $('.countsilver').click(function(){
        balance+=150000;
        $("#bonus1").html(balance);
    });
});
```

```css
.circle{
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: solid 1px black;
 height: 33px;width: 33px;
 background: none;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.silver{
 background-color:#c0c0c0;
}
.gold{
 background-color:#ffd700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="selection countsilver" data-new-class="silver" style="display: none;">SILVER</a>
 <a class="selection countgold" data-new-class="gold" style="display: none;">GOLD</a>
 <div class="circle" id="16"><p id="z16"></p></div>

 <p>Bonus 1 gain = <span id="bonus1"></span>
```

can someone tells me correct way to do it?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is you've declared the balance variable as string object.

```
var balance = '0';
```

So it will concatenate 150000 every time.
You must declare balance as

```
var balance = 0;
```

Now your balance object will act as an integer, now it will add 0 + 150000 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var currentCircleId = '';
var balance=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".circle").click(function(){
        $(".selection").toggle();
        currentCircleId = $(this).attr('id');
    });
    $('.selection').click(function(){
        $(".selection").toggle();
        var newClass = $(this).data('new-class');
        $('#' + currentCircleId).removeClass('gold silver').addClass(newClass);
    });

    $('.countsilver').click(function(){
        balance+=150000;
        $("#bonus1").html(balance);
    });
});
```

```css
.circle{
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: solid 1px black;
 height: 33px;width: 33px;
 background: none;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.silver{
 background-color:#c0c0c0;
}
.gold{
 background-color:#ffd700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="selection countsilver" data-new-class="silver" style="display: none;">SILVER</a>
 <a class="selection countgold" data-new-class="gold" style="display: none;">GOLD</a>
 <div class="circle" id="16"><p id="z16"></p></div>

 <p>Bonus 1 gain = <span id="bonus1"></span>
```